# Chat Onebox Raw Text File Links

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Oftentimes, while testing code or linking to raw GitHub, I find myself wishing that raw text or program files would one box. For example, the link:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy/master/examples/MathTest.vt

should one-box; I want the person with whom I'm working to be able to read that file in chat. Similarly, it would be helpful for some pastebins (small enough for chat, at least) in displaying outputs for programs.

So, to sum: [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for chat to one-box raw text files.